# Retrieve value larger than a threshold value from numpy array optimally

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm using python 3.x. I have a numpy array of shape (29982,29982) & a list of shape 29982. The sample array looks like

```
array([[1,5,7,2,9...],
       [2,6,4,1,5...],
       [7,9,1,12,4...],
       ...
       ...
       [6,8,13,2,4...]])
```

The sample list looks like

```
['John','David','Josua',......,'Martin']
```

I would like to get a pandas dataframe combining this array & list such that array value should be greater than 5. The dataframe should look like

```
        'John'  'David'   'Josua'
'John'    0       0         7
'David'   0       6         0
'Josua'   7       9         0
....
'Martin'  6       8         13
```

Can you please suggest me how should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create the dataframe from the array with `pd.DataFrame`, passing your list as `index` and `columns`. Then use `df.where` to keep only values that are greater than 5:

```py
arr = [...]
lst = ['John','David','Josua',...,'Martin']

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=lst, columns=lst)
df = df.where(df > 5, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`numpy.ma.masked_where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_where.html) to process on numpy array

```py
arr = np.array([[1,5,7,2,],
                [2,6,4,1,],
                [7,9,1,12],
                [6,8,13,2]])

lst = ['John','David','Josua', 'Martin']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.ma.masked_where(arr<=5, arr).filled(0), index=lst, columns=lst)
```

```
print(df)

        John  David  Josua  Martin
John       0      0      7       0
David      0      6      0       0
Josua      7      9      0      12
Martin     6      8     13       0
```